# $T:M(n, \mathbb R)\to M(n, \mathbb R)$, $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ with $| A| \ne 0$, such that $T(X)=AX$. Find tr$(T)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I really cant understand what could be tr(T) actually. Also how to show T is non singular with rank n^2, please need a help with elaboration. Actually I found from somewhere that tr(T)= n*tr(A) regarding this l. t I have mentioned, but how? w. r. t std basis of M(n, R), m(T) gives a diagonal n^2*n^2 diagonal which does not satisfy that trace property. I'm wrong somewhere, please help to find that

Comment: First, can you please put the question in the question, not just the title. Second, this is not legible as it is; please use MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: cant understand sir where am I wrong? this is question answer site na? I can not even ask my querry?

Comment: If you want an answer then please **ask** the question, in a readable way. For a start, you could format in MathJax: please see http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020

Comment: thnx, next time I'll do that & for now if you have understood it please help

Comment: I highly recommend that you study [the guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). Otherwise the negative attention your questions attract will continue.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a finite dimensional linear space, with basis $\{x_1,\ldots,x_m\}$, and $T:X\to X$ a linear transformation, defined as
$$
Tx_i=\sum_{i=1}^m t_{i,j}x_j,
$$
then its trace is defined to be Tr$(T)=\sum_{i=1}^n t_{ii}$.

In the question, consider as a basis, $E_{ij}$, $i,j=1,\ldots,n$, the matrix with $1$ in the $(i,j)$ place, and zeroes everywhere else.

Then 
$$
T(E_{i,j})=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k,i}E_{k,j}
$$ 
and hence 
$$
\text{Tr}(T)=n(a_{1,1}+\cdots+a_{n,n})=n\text{Tr}(A).
$$

Also note that if $X=(x_1\,x_2\cdots x_n)\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, where $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ re the columns of $X$, then $T(X)=(Ax_1\,Ax_2\cdots Ax_n)$. So if $T(X)=0$, then $Ax_1=\cdots=Ax_n=0$, and since $A$ is nonsingular, so is $T$.

In fact, $p_T(\lambda)=\big(p_A(\lambda)\big)^n$, where $p_A$ and $p_T$ are the characteristic polynomials of $A$ and $T$, respectively.

Comment: sorry cant understand what you have taken the transformation sir, please explain, & also the last line

Comment: specially the last line

Comment: @PriyaDey a finite dimensional linear transformation is injective if and only if it is surjective.

Comment: please understand my question, I want to know about how tr(T) = n* tr(A) here? please help in that case

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $\{E_{ij} : 1 \le i, j\le n\}$ be the canonical basis of the space $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. The trace $\operatorname{Tr} T$ is the sum of diagonal elements of the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. this basis.

If we denote the columns of $A = (a_{ij})$ by $A = \begin{bmatrix} A_1 & A_2 & \cdots & A_n\end{bmatrix}$, verify that
$$T(E_{ij}) = AE_{ij} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \cdots & 0 & A_i & 0 & \cdots & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ki}E_{kj}$$
where the $i$-th column of $A$ appears as the $j$-th column here.

Therefore the diagonal elements of the matrix of $T$ are $$\underbrace{a_{11}, \ldots, a_{11}}_n, \underbrace{a_{22}, \ldots, a_{22}}_n, \ldots, \underbrace{a_{nn}, \ldots, a_{nn}}_n$$ so $$\operatorname{Tr} T = n\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii} =n \operatorname{Tr} A$$

Comment: how all columns become 0? you are saying tr(T)= tr(A) here also?  but how?

Comment: @PriyaDey Edit your question with details of what you tried, and I'll explain some more.

Comment: how the last line please explain